# using dataset variable values as IN clause values in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset in which I store all the values to be used in IN clause elsewhere.

```
DATA INVALUES;
INPUT INVAL;
DATALINES;
1
2
3
;
RUN;
```

I have to use the invalues in another dataset as below.

```
DATA OUTPUT;
SET INPUT;
IF A IN ( --- INVAL  values from dataset INVALUES ----);
;
RUN;
```

Could this be done in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a macro variable for this.

```
/* Put the inval values in a comma separated macro variable  */
proc sql;
select inval into:inval separated by ","
from invalues;

/* prints the macro variable in the log */
%put &inval; /* 1,2,3 */

/* use the macrovariable in the IF statement */
DATA OUTPUT;
SET INPUT;
IF A IN &inval;
RUN;
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your reply... incase of the in clause values being characters, how to enclose them in to single quotes' '.kindly advise.

Comment: No problem. Try `separated by "','"` in the sql step and `'&inval.'` in the `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

A neater way is to use a subquery in SQL, no need to worry about the datatype/quoting.

```
proc sql ;
  create table output as
  select *
  from input 
  where a in(select distinct inval from invalues) ;
quit ;
```